# Databricks - CSV not loading properly

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have a simple csv file that's pipe delimited that I can load into Databricks, then disuplay the df and it displays nicely. I then try with my main dataset which is formatted the same way and an export from SQL server. After it loads the output shows that it was loaded (lists the field names and the data type it inferred -- all string though which isn't a good sign)

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").options(header='true', quote='"', delimiter="|",ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace='true',inferSchema='true').load("/mnt/gl/mainfile.csv")
```

Then I do display (df) and I don't see a nice display. Instead it shows the following:

```
Job 34 View

(Stages: 1/1)

Job 35 View

(Stages: 1/1)

Job 36 View

(Stages: 1/1)
```

Obviously the csv is at fault here but I've no idea how to go about solving this - I've already been careful with how I export it from SQL server so not sure what I'd do differently there.

Comment: try to read as a text file and see how the lines are.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved it. If you get a similar issue it might mean your csv is not formatted properly. Open up your cv using a text editor like Ron's Editor then visually inspect the data. On my dataset for some reason the final field which is a $ amount, had a "  in front of it , but not at the end of it.

e.g. "12344.67

Not sure why SQL Server would do that (I was using Import/Export Wizard) but I got rid of the " delimiter from my exported csv and it now works fine

Comment: good find. yes, csv is a terrible format (thanks M$), but that's what we have.